# Find two number whose sum is 45 using mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a 2GB file stored in HDFS. The content of the file looks like:

```
1
24
65
77
```

....
One number in each line. I want to know two number(any two) whose sum is 45 using map reduce.

Can anyone tell what should be logic in mapper and what for reducer?

Comment: 2G isn't enough data to justify using Hadoop... Writing and using an algorithm that runs on a single file could probably be done faster than installing Hadoop and writing mapreduce... In any case, you must read the entire file into a single reducer anyway because you must compare each number to all others. If no numbers are negative, then best that the mapper could do is to filter out all values over 45.

Comment: I just gave an example of 2gb, it can be huge also. My main concern was how we can write MapReduce logic to do it efficiently. As you said we have to load full data in one reducer, I agree with that but is there a better way of doing this with multiple reducer(for parallelism)

Comment: Not that I know of. Each block would be limited to 128Mb in size. Let's say that you don't find two numbers in the first block, then you must scan the second (and later) blocks with all numbers from the first. This solution you're looking for isn't suitable for divide and conquer algorithms

Comment: So you mean to say we can't run map reduce jobs for this kind of problem, right?

Comment: That's not what I said. Just that the only algorithm I can think of wouldn't be any more efficient using mapreduce than running the same process on a single machine. Obligatory reference https://adamdrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @cricket_007 with his concerns, there is a way you could do this with multiple mappers and reducers in one MapReduce job:

In the mapper, let's assume `x` is the original value and `y = 45 - x`. For each `x`, create an entry with a key of `(min(x, y), max(x, y))`. So for example, if the original is `15`, then you'd have `(15, 30)`, while if the original was `40`, you'd have `(5, 40)`. The smaller value should always be first, so the keys will match up appropriately. The value of the entry should then be `x`.

In the reducer, if you have two entries with the same key but different values, then you have a match, and can report. Because there may be duplicates, you may find multiple entries with the same key and the same values. These should be ignored, since they don't match your requirements.